# Validation for String if null or if empty or any value

Tags: java

This is a scenario where I am making an API call which provides me some random value if I pass a null value or any value to a String field. Below is the API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/employee/details", method = GET)
 public void getEmployeeDetails(@RequestParam(value = "employeeSalCode", required = false) String employeSalcode
@RequestParam(value = "employeeId", required = false) String employeId );
```

Now we have removed the fetching of employee details basing on employeesalcode. But when our API is called with any null value or any string passwed some random value is returned from the API.

I like to give validation check for the employeeSalcode as below

```
 if(isNull(employeeSalcode) || isEmpty(employeeSalCode)){
 System.out.println("Sorry Employee details by salcode is deprecated");
 }
```

Again if values passed

```
if(nonNull(employeeSalcode)){
 System.out.println("Sorry Employee details by salcode is deprecated");
 }
```

Now my validation looks weird as I am validating null and nonnull both at sametime. I there anyway I can validate the String in these conditions.

Comment: ok deprecated sounds great!

Answer (score -2):

Use this, In our api call data may contain null string. 
So I declare a final static null string in C class. 
Now checking all of the criteria for null string in my util class.

```
   class C {
     public static final String NULL_STR = "null";
   }

   public static boolean isStrEmpty(String str) {
       return str == null || str.isEmpty()
            || str.toLowerCase().equals(C.NULL_STR);
   }
```

Comment: The second, third, and fourth conditions are equivalent, and two of them are therefore redundant.

Comment: Or converting a string to lowercase to compare it to an empty String, especially when we already know it cannot possibly be empty at this point, having tested exactly that twice already. Empty strings are not case-sensitive. Code is mere nonsense.

Comment: Did you check the conditions of your code? ....and why are you turning a String to lowercase to check if it's empty???

Comment: Actually this method was created to serve different purposes. Sometimes our api can send null string like this. name = "null" from database. That's why I checked all the possible criteria. When it contains "null" as a string above code will work just fine :)

Comment: @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/details/{param1}/{param2}", method = GET)  Use your variable values instead of param value